# "git push origin master " in Dulwich

Tags: git, github, dulwich

I am new to git and python and I was trying to do :

```
git push origin master using Dulwich
```

I have cloned a remote repository to local repo "local_repo" and then trying to do something like:

```
porcelain.push(local_repo,'git://github.com/myusername/myrepo')
```

and it shows error:

```
"dulwich.errors.GitProtocolError: You can't push to git://github.com/myusername/myrepo Use https://github.com/myusername/myrepo.git"
```

When I use :

```
porcelain.push(local_repo,'https://github.com/myusername/myrepo.git')
```

It shows error:

```
"dulwich.errors.GitProtocolError: unexpected http response 401"
```

Please tell me how do I go about it

Comment: You need to provide the appropriate authentication parameters for the request to go through. The `401` stands for invalid authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't push to that repository as you don't have the necessary permissions. You can pass the ceredentials as part of the URL if you like:

```
git clone https://username:password@github.com/username/repository.git
```

I would use an ssh key for github though.

EDIT: It seems like porcelain has a bug working with private repositories. I've opened an issue here: https://github.com/jelmer/dulwich/issues/507